# issue with date and time zone how to get date without time zone?

Tags: java

I tried to do convert between date in Tics to UTC date time format - 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss'

```
public static DateFormat getFormat() {
    String systemLocale = System.getProperty("user.language"); //$NON-NLS-1$ 
    Locale locale = new Locale(systemLocale);
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM, locale);
    return dateFormat;
}

public static Object getFormatedValue(Object value) {
        String updated = (strValue).replaceAll(pattern, "$1"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(updated));
        return getFormat().format(new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
}

public static Object getOdataValue(Object value) throws ParseException {

    DateFormat dateFormat = getFormat();

    Date parse = dateFormat.parse(value.toString());
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(parse.getTime());

    return "\"/Date(" + calendar.getTimeInMillis() + ")/\""; //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$

}
```

The problem that I got the result of dtae time with UTC for example -

1393358368000 = Tue, 25 Feb 2014 19:59:28 GMT

Your time zone: 2/25/2014 9:59:28 PM GMT+2

The result from this code is 2/25/2014 21:59:28 PM

How I can get the result without time zone ? in this case I want that the result will be ue, 25 Feb 2014 19:59:28 GMT 
Can I have tick and got different result with and without UTC ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Can I have tick and got different result with and without UTC ?" - it's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: look on my example 1393358368000 = Tue, 25 Feb 2014 19:59:28 GMT in my code the result is Tue, 25 Feb 2014 21:59:28 GMT. How I can get that the result will be without the GMT+2 meaning Tue, 25 Feb 2014 19:59:28

Comment: The result from your code isn't that at all - it's a string of the form `"/Date(1393358368000)/"` - where are you seeing the value with GMT+2? Note that you don't need to create a `Calendar` at all - just call `parse.getTime()` to get the same millis value.

Comment: getOdataValue = /Date(1393358368000)/` but getFormatedValue will be Tue, 25 Feb 2014 21:59:28

Comment: Ah, right. It wasn't clear what you meant. I'll add an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but if all you want is to make your `DateFormat` use UTC, that's easy:

```
public static DateFormat getFormat() {
    String systemLocale = System.getProperty("user.language"); //$NON-NLS-1$ 
    Locale locale = new Locale(systemLocale);
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
        DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM, locale);
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
    return dateFormat;
}
```

(Any reason you're not using `Locale.getDefault()` for the default locale, by the way? Or letting the `DateFormat` pick it itself?)

Also note that you're creating calendars for no reason at all. Your `getFormattedValue` and `getOdataValue` methods can be simplified to:

```
public static Object getFormattedValue(Object value) {
    String updated = (strValue).replaceAll(pattern, "$1"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    long millis = Long.parseLong(updated);
    return getFormat().format(new Date(millis));
}

public static Object getOdataValue(Object value) throws ParseException {
    DateFormat dateFormat = getFormat();
    Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(value.toString());
    return "\"/Date(" + date.getTime() + ")/\""; //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
}
```

Comment: does dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC") will remove the timeZone from the dateFormat ?

Comment: @user1365697: No, it will set the time zone to be UTC. The fact that the time zone appears at all is just part of the "medium format" you're requesting - it's locale-specific. (That format doesn't show a time zone for me... are you *sure* you're looking at the result of `getFormattedValue` rather than a `Date` object with its default `toString()` representation?)

Comment: what is the different between them ?

Comment: The problem that the DB is saved the data without the time zone and then do a convert. I show that date time with time zone

Comment: @user1365697: I'm afraid I'm really not following you at all. If this doesn't answer your question, I suggest you take a while to make your question *much* clearer. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and really take the time to make things clear. We don't know how you're fetching from the database, what you mean by "without the time zone" (did you store the UTC value or the local value? How did you store it?) or how you're showing the date, or which time zone you want to show it in.